PowerShell Script to Check If Chrome Profiles Are Running Not Working As Expected
I have a PowerShell script that aims to check if specific Chrome profiles are already running and, if not, start them. However, the script is not correctly detecting running profiles and is opening duplicate instances. Here is the script I am using:
Changes: Thanks to Mathias.
Issue: The script now seems to realise that the default profile is running, but will duplicate all the other profiles.
        # Function to request elevated permissions (run as admin)
function Test-Admin {
    $isAdmin = ([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Groups -match "S-1-5-32-544")
    if (-not $isAdmin) {
        Write-Host "This script requires administrator privileges. Restarting with elevated rights."
        # Start a new PowerShell process with admin rights
        Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs
        exit
    }
}

# Request admin rights at the start of the script
Test-Admin

# Full path to Chrome executable
$chromePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

# List of Chrome profiles to open
$profiles = @("Default", "Profile 10", "Profile 7", "Profile 8", "Profile 9", "Profile 3", "Profile 2", "Profile 6", "Profile 5", "Profile 17", "Profile 20", "Profile 18", "Profile 4", "Profile 1", "Profile 21", "Profile 19", "Profile 15")

# Get all chrome processes (filtering out renderer and crashpad processes)
$chromeProcesses = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "chrome.exe" -and $_.CommandLine -notlike "*--type=renderer*" -and $_.CommandLine -notlike "*--type=crashpad-handler*" }

# Loop through each profile
foreach ($profile in $profiles) {
    Write-Host "Checking if Chrome profile $profile is running..."

    $profileRunning = $false

    # Check if any process has the profile argument in its command line
    foreach ($process in $chromeProcesses) {
        if ($process.CommandLine -like "*--profile-directory=$profile*" -or $process.CommandLine -like "*--profile-directory=`"$profile`"") {
            $profileRunning = $true
            Write-Host "Profile $profile is already running with process ID $($process.ProcessId)."
            break
        }
    }

    # If the profile isn't running, start Chrome with that profile
    if (-not $profileRunning) {
        Write-Host "Starting Chrome with profile $profile at $(Get-Date)"
        Start-Process -FilePath $chromePath -ArgumentList "--profile-directory=`"$profile`"" -NoNewWindow
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 # Adding a brief delay for performance
    }
}

Write-Host "All requested profiles checked. Only non-running profiles were started."

Old code:
    # Function to request elevated permissions (run as admin)
function Test-Admin {
    $isAdmin = ([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Groups -match "S-1-5-32-544")
    if (-not $isAdmin) {
        Write-Host "This script requires administrator privileges. Restarting with elevated rights."
        # Start a new PowerShell process with admin rights
        Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs
        exit
    }
}

# Request admin rights at the start of the script
Test-Admin

# Full path to Chrome executable
$chromePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

# List of Chrome profiles to open
$profiles = @("Default", "Profile 10", "Profile 7", "Profile 8", "Profile 9", "Profile 3", "Profile 2", "Profile 6", "Profile 5", "Profile 17", "Profile 20", "Profile 18", "Profile 4", "Profile 1", "Profile 21", "Profile 19", "Profile 15")

# Get all chrome processes (filtering out renderer and crashpad processes)
$chromeProcesses = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "chrome.exe" -and $_.CommandLine -notlike "*--type=renderer*" -and $_.CommandLine -notlike "*--type=crashpad-handler*" }

# Loop through each profile
foreach ($profile in $profiles) {
    Write-Host "Checking if Chrome profile $profile is running..."

    $profileRunning = $false

    # Check if any process has the profile argument in its command line
    foreach ($process in $chromeProcesses) {
        if ($process.CommandLine -like "*--profile-directory=$profile*" -or $process.CommandLine -like "*--profile-directory=`"$profile`"") {
            $profileRunning = $true
            Write-Host "Profile $profile is already running with process ID $($process.ProcessId)."
            break
        }
    }

    # If the profile isn't running, start Chrome with that profile
    if (-not $profileRunning) {
        Write-Host "Starting Chrome with profile $profile at $(Get-Date)"
        Start-Process -FilePath $chromePath -ArgumentList "--profile-directory=`"$profile`"" -NoNewWindow
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 # Adding a brief delay for performance
    }
}

Write-Host "All requested profiles checked. Only non-running profiles were started."

Problem:
The script successfully starts the Chrome profiles, but it fails to detect running profiles, resulting in duplicate instances of profiles that are already open.
What I've Tried:
Ensured the profile names in the $profiles array match the actual folder names in the Chrome User Data directory.
Added detailed logging to check the command lines of running Chrome processes.
Added delays to ensure profiles start correctly.
Verified that the script is running with administrative privileges.
Question:
How can I modify the script to correctly detect if a Chrome profile is already running and prevent it from opening duplicates?
Additional Information:
PSVersion                      5.1.22621.4391
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.22621.4391
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

Looks like you should be filtering for "*--profile-directory=`"$profile*" (don't skip the quotation mark after the command line switch)

Thank you, Mathias. Although it checks the default profile, I still see duplicate profiles from other instances.
